# How to apply a function all numpy array elements

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1D numpy array of integers.

When my python script starts executing, the numpy array consists of all zeroes.

I want to apply the following function to every element in the array:

a [i] = i * 2.0

In that function, i is the array index and a[i] is the element at that index.

How can I do this in a vectorized fashion (as fast as possible without writing an explicit loop in python)?

I know how to do the multiplication.  The problem is that I don't know how to get at the array index in a vectorized fashion.

Edit:

I am getting the pointer to the array buffer from a C DLL.  Then I am using np.ctypeslib.as_array to construct a numpy array from the memory buffer pointer returned from the C DLL.

I need to update the contents of the memory buffer pointer returned by the C DLL and I thought that I could accomplish that very quickly using numpy.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but just `np.arange(arr.size) * 2` or `np.indices(arr.shape) * 2`?

Comment: Does theoriginal value of `a[i]` play any role in the calculation?  Looks like this is just a function of the index, not `a` itself.

Comment: No, the original value of a[i] does not matter. only index does.  But I need to modify the buffer in the C DLL.  Please see my edit update.

Comment: I haven't played around with numpy much, but if it was a regular array, I'm pretty sure the map() function would work, but idk if it will with a bumpy array. Looks like it should though.

Comment: for numpy there's [`apply_along_axis()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html). but if you're working with c maybe there are better solutions

Comment: How fast does this need to be? If you're toying with the memory and you *really* need it to be fast, why not write something in C instead of Python?

Answer (score 0):

Use `arange` to build an array of the desired values, and slice-assign the values into the array you want to fill:

```
a[:] = numpy.arange(0, len(a)*2, 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Where my_array is your array of zeros:

```
map(lambda x, i: x + i*2.0, my_array, np.arange(0,len(my_array))
```

Do note that the map() function behaves differently depending on if you're in Python2 or Python3. In Python2, you are returned a list. In Python3, you are returned an iterable (which, if I remember correctly, has lazy eval). You can easily convert this iterable to a list using the list() function.

Comment: This will be slow, and won't write to the array's buffer.

Comment: Depending on the size of his array, it may be fast enough. Additionally, you can easily make it write to the array's buffer.

Comment: It's still going to be interpreting Python bytecode and building wrapper objects for every element of the array. Also, the array's original values aren't supposed to be involved in the computation.

Comment: OP fairly directly states that his array is initially populated with zeroes.

Comment: Whoops, that is true. Involving the original values is merely redundant rather than outright incorrect, then.